# Rewrite sendevent.c from C to Java

Tags: java, android, c, url-rewriting

In android, I use sendevent to simulation click and drag event. the code is:

```
String[] events = new String[7];
events[0] = "sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 0";
events[1] = "sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 53 " + x1;
events[2] = "sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54 " + y1;
events[3] = "sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 58 31";
events[4] = "sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 50 2";
events[5] = "sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 2 0";
events[6] = "sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0";
Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");  
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());  
for (String event : events) {
    os.writeBytes(event + "\n");
    os.flush();
}
```

yes, it can achieve result, but it is very slow and unstable, every sendevent will new a process to do it.

then I find the sendevent source in https://www.assembla.com/code/android-gb-for-sharp-is01/git/nodes/debug/system/core/toolbox/sendevent.c, it write by c, and eveytime it will open a file and write the args, it will create a new process every time, so I hava a idea, rewrite the sendevent to Java and direct use in android code, it only need open the file once and write all args.

Is it feasible? Can it will speed my code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's feasible, you need to emulate the sequence of bytes that represents the input_event structure and write that to a file named `/dev/input/event1`.  It should speed up your code quite a lot as shelling out is a pretty expensive operation.

This question ( [Using C struct in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287903/using-c-struct-in-java) ) has lots of useful information pertaining to the cooperation between C structs and Java.

Btw, in the mean time I had a look at [Preon](http://preon.codehaus.org/) (I didn't know that library) and it looks really great.  Next time I have to mess with low-level telegrams I'm definitely going to give it a try!

Comment: I don't want use Preon, it looks like big, just use java api may better. I have write a simple class by java. see it https://gist.github.com/Yhzhtk/6595875, I am not sure it's right, Tomorrow I will test it. Thanks!

Comment: @Yhzhtk using nio is indeed another very reasonable approach, at first I don't see any serious issues with your code, there may be an byte order (endian) issue but that should be easy to debug and correct.  Btw, I'd appreciate if you could post back what speed gain you achieved with this solution on your platform.

Comment: When I run it in android, a error appears `java.io.IOException: write failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)`. It is a byte order issue. How can I get the right struct byte order? I don't write c, the struct is a problem to me.

Comment: I have update time byte lenght, then error `Invalid argument` is not appears, but I can't get the send events. I find the [Source](https://www.assembla.com/code/android-gb-for-sharp-is01/git/nodes/debug/system/core/toolbox/sendevent.c) has a call ioctl(fd, EVIOCGVERSION, &version) before write, it says get driver version, whether I should use it before write and How can I use [ioctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) in Java, or I should not use FileOutputStream to write data.

Comment: I think it's best to restart with a new question with the present state as a starting point, we're getting quite far from the initial question here.  Now, I don't think you actually *have* to perform that ioctl, and if you really must [it's not easy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163166/calling-ioctl-from-java-how-is-it-done).